# Compress File to .RAR through Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, tasks, rar

I have this batch code to compress a csv file into a .rar file:

```
call "c:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep1 C:\path\file.rar C:\path\file.csv
```

Manually running the program creates the .rar file without any problem. Now I want to run this batch file automatically a certain amount of time through Task Scheduler.

So I create the scheduled task making sure the file.bat is executed through the task. Executing this task shows a message dialog from WinRAR which reads like this:

**Can't create __rar_0.XXX** Where XXX can be any random three numbers

**Access denied**

The task is created in a normal User account and not with Admin privileges, however I'd like to think that's not the reason why this error is thrown back at me since running the .bat file manually doesn't require for authorization, nor the User Warning prompt appears when running this file, so perhaps I'm missing more WinRAR commands in order for this batch file to run without problems through the Task Scheduler?

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: If you want to do compression via command line, use `rar.exe` instead (located in the WinRAR directory)...

Comment: WinRAR uses a temporary file, which might be created in the working directory; if I am right, you could prepend `cd /D "%TEMP%"` to change the working directory to the temporary directory of the current user, where the access privileges should be sufficient...

Comment: check under which account the scheduled task is running, perhaps the user is not allowed to write at the location you specified. If you want to set a working / temp directory use the -w switch (http://acritum.com/winrar/console-rar-manual)

Comment: And to elaborate on what @Marged said, I believe the account the task is running under also needs a password.